# Wordpress not showing the list of menu item in custom Archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, navbar, custom-wordpress-pages

Here is the code which shows navigation on my header.php

```
        <nav class="navbar nav">
        <div class="logo">
            <h2><span class="golden">Being </span>Online</h2>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="nav__checkbox" id="nav-toggle">
        <label for="nav-toggle" class="button">
            <span class="navigation__icon">&nbsp;</span>
        </label>
        <?php
                wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'theme_location' => 'menuLocation',
                    'menu_class'      => 'menu', 
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav__drawer',
                    'items_wrap'=>'<ul class="nav__drawer">%3$s</ul>'
                ));
        ?>
    </nav>
```

I have the following function in my Functions.php

```
    function add_classes_on_li($classes, $item, $args) {
    $classes = ['item', 'navlink'];
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class','add_classes_on_li',1,3);
```

It works fine on all pages except my *Archive-event.php* page. When I am on event archive, all I see is a navbar without the navigation links. How to fix this?

**UDPATE**

Commenting out this function fixes the issue. But is there a way to keep this function?

```
    // if(!is_admin() AND is_post_type_archive('event') AND is_main_query()) {

    //     $today = date('Ymd');
    //     $query->set('meta_key', 'event_date');
    //     $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    //     $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    //     $query->set('meta_query', array(
    //         array(
    //             'key' => 'event_date',
    //             'compare'=> '>=',
    //             'value' => $today,
    //             'type' => 'numeric'
    //         )
    //     ));
    // }
```

Comment: Do you have anything else in your functions.php that changes the archives pages and could have an effect on this? Also, if you have just made this change recently, you might be seeing an old version of this page. Have you cleared all caching (plugins, browser etc)?

Comment: Caching is not the issue. I have found the cause in functions.PHP. Please check

Comment: The code you commented out is changing the query for your "archive-event.php" page. I don't see how it would affect the navbar though, that's strange. Are there `else` clauses for that `if` that are now getting executed because that clause isn't anymore?What action is that code being called on?.

Comment: There are no else classes

Comment: Without having more information, all we can do is guess. And I'm out of guesses :) Can you update your question with any more information such as the full code in that function and what action it is being called for?

Comment: I have a very similar setup, also with customized archive query on an events archive page . Commenting the lines `"key" => ...` and `$query->set('meta_key', ...)` "solves" the problem (at least the nav is back). Seems like these meta key definitions somehow have side effects on wordpress navigation rendering …

Comment: The solution is given in this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/302370/104091.